# Peculiar MariaDB optimization results

Tags: optimization, mariadb

I started working on 10y old ongoing project. There is this one pain in the ass (caused by previous developers) - huge table, let's call it abc - 128GB of data, 16,5 mil rows, 120 columns. Of course it's very slow and causing a lot of problems. So we decided it is time to do something about it. We are running on AWS RDS Mariadb, we have multiple instances of databases running for various microservices, so I have access to snapshots/backups of PROD and restoring them just for this purpose - testing and optimizing this big table (databases on DEV/TEST  are not even close to be that full and big). For backend there is PHP framework and Doctrine as ORM.

So I started with dropping unused and unnecessary columns, together 30 columns (also refactored backend and entities, but unrelated to this problem). Great, first step!

Then I run queue (via RabbitMQ) which cleaned up some columns containing unnecessary large JSONs (due to the stupid way of exporting some entities, which is fixed now). These columns are used to store this data only, no search or selects.

Then I did some research (also about partitioning since there is column 'type' with 7 very specified never-to-be-changed-in-near-future values, but also next steps, not important now)

I ended up with running command optimize (yes I know in mariadb it will rebuild and analyse the table)

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE abc
```

And this worked! It run for about 2.5 hours and resulted in reduction of size **from 128GB to 46GB**! I was very happy with the results. I also checked the size via `information_schema.tables` and `data_length` for tables, it was correct. Tables also started to be noticeably faster (but not that fast as one would wish).

The time went by, I did some other things and about 2 weeks later I recreated another snapshot of PROD and started to test all optimization migrations with normal flow via backend Doctrine migrations etc. I did everything in the same order. First drop columns, then queue for JSONs, then OPTIMIZE TABLE. This time it took 5h and reduced the data from 128 to 124GB. And I am clueless, how and why.

The snapshots are 4w apart, the "older" version on which I run the commands first is 16 330 693 columns big, the "current" one is 16 649 545. So not a big difference. Snapshots are recreated with the same settings, same instance (m5 large), same everything, but suddenly optimize is not working. On the virtually same dataset. I even tried to drop one very big and very stupid composite index on this abc table and run the OPTIMIZE command again, to no avail.

Do you have any hints what I could have done differently? Because I tried it even third time, fresh snapshot, fresh build, fresh everything, same settings, same code, but I still can not replicate that 128 to 46 gigs optimization (yes I still have that snapshot/instance running and it is just fine and contains all the data)

Comment: *I also checked the size via information_schema.tables and **data_length** for tables, it was correct.* Is this value similar in all cases? except those for non-optimized table, of course..also check SELECT AVG(LENGTH(column)) for each char/binary/json column before and after the optimization - does these values matches?

Comment: @akina if you mean data_length for other tables it is more or less the same every time, system is active on PROD so each day there is more data, but compared with the size of DB and table, it's normal growth. For this table abc, only first time it went from 128GB to 46GB, second and third (on fresh instances of PROD snapshots only few days old) it went only to 124GB. I am now trying running it on fresh instances of the snapshot from the day, it was originally/first run and tested (which resulted in 46GB) to see if I can replicate it at least on this snapshot, it is from 23rd of October

Comment: @Akina but good point with AVG LENGTH I am going to check now. There is a lot of varchar columns, but also the 30 columns I dropped, they were all varchar. Also the reason I fixed (trimmed down to only necessary attributes) the JSON columns is to lower avg length of these columns, since there was a lot of gibberish from serializing php/doctrine entities into json

Comment: *if you mean data_length for other tables* You ask about only one table, is it? so all another tables are not interesting. What AVG lengths values were initially? after 128->48 GB optimization? 128->124 Gb optimization? compare these values...

Comment: For slow queries, show us the query and the relevant `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: `PARTITIONing` is unlikely to help with performance -- show the specifics.

Comment: Why was `OPTIMIZE` needed?  Did you delete lots of rows?  Etc.  See my bloghttps://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: "is 16 330 693 columns big" explain where that came from.

Comment: Some of the values in `SHOW TABLE STATUS` are _estimates_.  As such, they can change even without anything happening to the table.

Comment: I totally forgot to check this thread. So after comment from Akina I checked the AVG length of some columns and I found out that the JSON columns were same as on running prod database thus I found out that my optimisation queue did not worked. So I created fresh instance as copy of prod, checked all credentials, run the queue, checked that column is fixed, run the OPTIMIZE command and got back 46GB instead of 124GB. This was already successfully deployed on PROD without any hickups. I do not know where the error was, but probably somewhere between keyboard and chair. Case closed.